# does not appear boot dashboard after install spring tool plugin

Tags: spring, eclipse, plugins, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-marketplace

i am using **ubuntu** as operative system, currently I have downloaded **eclipse version 2020/06.**

After, I have installed **spring tool 3 standalone edition 3.9.14.RELEASE plugin** from the marketplace, but when i check window -> show view -> spring, I don't find the boot dashboard option.

[image]

In other computer which has windows 10 I have done the same steps but in this computer i have the boot dashboard option.

someone knows how i can solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: Please update to current Spring Tools 4 and current Eclipse. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: when I use a plain Eclipse JEE 2020-06 installation and install the Spring Tools 3 Standalone Edition extension from the Eclipse Marketplace, I get version 3.9.15 installed and I can see the Boot Dashboard extension showing up there. I don't know why you see version 3.9.14 instead. I would recommend to update to the latest Eclipse version and the latest Spring Tools 4 version, you can download a ready to use distribution of that at https://spring.io/tools.

Comment: From what I can see after installing 3.9.15 into that Eclipse version is that, depending on your JDK installation, you might end up with a more or less broken installation indeed. This might be the reason why you are not seeing the Boot Dashboard in your case. If this is the case, there is no easy solution for this other than upgrading to the latest versions.

Comment: I can't update the eclipse version becouse the following versions don't allow JDK 1.8, but i don't think that the problem is the version, i thinck that the problem is the operative system, due to in windows work well

Comment: @roberto No, that's not true. The current Eclipse version supports Java 8 and even older Java versions. The fact that Eclipse is a Java application that itself uses a higher Java version to run is not relevant to your code. Just make sure, in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_ to configure the JDKs you want to use (for coding and for running your code).

Comment: @howlger I am not sure, in this page https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation, saids that the newer versions than 2020-06 is required java 11 or newer, in addition when I installed the last version, i had different problems to run my application.
I have resolved my problem downloading STS instead eclipse, in this case the spring plugin works fine.

Comment: You misread it. That's about the Java to run Eclipse, not the Java versions that are support by Eclipse. Current Eclipse and current STS which is based on current Eclipse support Java 8 for sure. Your _different problems_ (what ever that should mean) might be caused by your configuration, e.g. when you missed to configure a Java 8 JDK in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_ and/or use it in your project and launch configurations.